# Sequelize - use sequelize functions to convert iLike queries to be MySQL friendly

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I generally use PostgreSQL, and this is my first time using MySQL with Sequelize. I learned that MySQL does not support `iLike`, and I'm trying to convert my `iLike` to be MySQL friendly (so-to-speak).

I managed to successfully accomplish the below with one of my queries.

```
where: {
  [Op.or]: [
    {
      name: {
       [Op.iLike]: `%${searchTerm || ''}`,
      },
    },
    {
      description: {
        [Op.iLike]: `%${searchTerm || ''}`,
      },
    },
  ],
},

**Converted To**

where: {
  [Op.or]: [
    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('name')), {
      [Op.like]: `%${searchTerm || ''}`,
    }),
    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('description')), {
      [Op.like]: `%${searchTerm || ''}`,
    }),
  ],
},
```

What I'm struggling with is converting the following. I'd appreciate any input I could get.

```
ingredients = ['%salt%', '%pepper%'];

where: {
  ingredient: {
    [Op.iLike]: {
      [Op.any]: ingredients,
    },
  },
},
SQL - WHERE "Ingredient"."ingredient" ILIKE ANY (ARRAY['%salt%','%pepper%']);

**Attempt to Convert**

where: Sequelize.where(
  Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('ingredient')),
  {
    [Op.like]: {
      [Op.any]: ingredients,
    },
  }
),
SQL - WHERE lower(`ingredient`) LIKE ANY ('%salt%', '%pepper%')  It seems like ingredients is not passed as an array compared to the above code.
```

Comment: Does `// In Postgres, Op.like/Op.iLike/Op.notLike can be combined to Op.any:
      [Op.like]: { [Op.any]: ['cat', 'hat'] }  // LIKE ANY ARRAY['cat', 'hat']
` mean it's only for PG?

Comment: Isn't the first example with `OR` and `iLIke` the same as the second one with `iLike` and `any`?

Comment: Hey thanks for taking a look. Yes, thats the raw SQL query returned from that PG query. In MySql, `iLike` does not work.

Comment: And in the first example, I'm checking to see if the columns `name` or `description` contain the search term. In the second example; I'm checking to see if there are any `ingredient` that has the search terms in the array. Basically return me all ingredients that contain `['%salt%', '%pepper%']`. If I'm not mistaken `[Op.or]` checks across multiple columns (`name` or `description`), while `[Op.any]` checks in a single column `name` only for instance (return to me all whose name matches `James`, but will not check to see if another column contains `James`).

Comment: But you can use the same column in `OR` as many times as an array length

Answer (score 1):

This way worked to me, maybe this way help you.

```
where: {
  title: {
    [Op.like]: ['%' + title + '%'],
  },
},
```